# Android multiple permission error

Tags: android, permissions, camera

The situation : When camera(imageview) is click, it will prompt multiple permission.

1. If user select DENY on 1st permission and 2nd permission, it's working.
2. If user select ALLOW on 1st permission and 2nd permission, its working.
3. If user select DENY on 1st permission and ALLOW on 2nd permission, it's working.
4. If user select ALLOW on 1st permission and DENY on 2nd permission, error will appear.

Here is code (extends Fragment) :

```
private static String[] PERMISSIONS_CAMERA = {Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
            Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.CAMERA};


 img_1 = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.img_1);
 img_1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startCamera();
            }
        });    
        private void StartCamera() {
        requestPermissions(PERMISSIONS_CAMERA, REQUEST_CAMERA);
    }

   private void OpenCamera() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CAMERA);
        this.bitmap = null;
    }
    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

     switch (requestCode) {
            // For camera
            case REQUEST_CAMERA:
                 if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    OpenCamera();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Go to settings and enable permissions", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                break;
    }

}
```

Error Log :

```
  java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result
  ResultInfo{who=@android:requestPermissions:, request=131073,
  result=-1, data=Intent {
  act=android.content.pm.action.REQUEST_PERMISSIONS (has extras) }} to
  activity {app.swb.mont/app.swb.mont.ui.activity.MainActivity}:
  java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent {
  act=android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE
  cmp=com.sec.android.app.camera/.Camera } from ProcessRecord{b2f7ceb
  28260:app.swb.mont/u0a392} (pid=28260, uid=10392) with revoked
  permission android.permission.CAMERA at    android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4925)
                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4968)
                   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:222)
                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1849)
                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7229)
                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
                Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent { act=android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE
 cmp=com.sec.android.app.camera/.Camera } from ProcessRecord{b2f7ceb
 28260:app.swb.mont/u0a392} (pid=28260, uid=10392) with revoked
 permission android.permission.CAMERA
```

Comment: In your switch case grantResults.length > 0 true but u didn't gave camera permission so its throwing exception

Comment: Check specifically for camera permission while calling OpenCamera()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your are not handling the onRequestPermissionResult correctly.
On this line

```
if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                OpenCamera();}
```

Your are checking only the first permission that your requested witch is in this case `Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` (position == 0) and you trigger your camera function witch require the permission at position == 2

Solution

```
if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[2] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                OpenCamera();}
```

OR

```
if (grantResults.length > 0 && (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && grantResults[1] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && grantResults[2] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) ) {
                OpenCamera();}
```

// You can also use a loop

Comment: I see. How about if only have 1 permission. Is it still working for more than 1 array ?

Comment: Found the solutions ! Thank you guys.

Answer (score 0):

that's because you check only 1st permission result, and don't check 2nd: `grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED`. You need to check
`grantResults[1] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED`  as well

Answer (score 0):

If your requirement is if all the permissions given then only it has to work you can try like this

```
@Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[]permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        switch (requestCode) {
            // For camera
            case REQUEST_CAMERA:
                if (grantResults.length > 0) {
                    boolean permGiven = true;
                    for(int i=0; i<grantResults.length; i++){
                        if(grantResults[i] != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
                            permGiven = false;
                    }
                    if(permGiven)
                        OpenCamera();
                    else
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Go to settings and enable permissions", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Go to settings and enable permissions", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                break;


        }
    }
```